# How to change RGB to CMYK without affecting blending mode?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cmyk, color-conversion, rgb, blend-modes

In Illustrator, I create some designs in RGB mode (eg: glow effect and blending mode), If I drag and drop the CMYK document some blending options are changing. So please give me the solution for this problem, I am very confused by this problem...

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The blending mode could be changing because there's a color shift caused by going from RGB to CMYK. Assuming you'll be printing it on paper, will it be a (a) home inkjet printer or a (b) commercial press?

If it's (a) an inkjet printer, you can leave it in RGB mode.

If it's (b) press, it will require the the CMYK mode.

If (b), I suggest you change the colors all to CMYK, and redo the blends. It will probably be faster than trying to find how to fix the existing ones.

Comment: It's not about color. Blending modes are inherently different in RGB vs CMYK. (See [duplicate](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/74649/problem-converting-cmyk-to-rgb-for-print))