# Opacity gradients fail in CMYK and FOGRA 29

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency, gradient, cmyk

Following [Conversion from RGB to CMYK loses mesh gradient transparency](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/156685/conversion-from-rgb-to-cmyk-loses-mesh-gradient-transparency) , I replaced the mesh gradients with simple transparency gradients in Illustrator CS5.1. Note that the blue and red emojis have white spots on the eyes and a gradient in the face color:

[image: emojis in Illustrator]

When I save as a PDF with Uncoated FOGRA 29 color profile, those two emojis lose the white spots and the gradient in the face color. Here is the result in PDF, which is also missing those nuances after I upload to the manufacturer's website:

[image]

I used an ellipse and then the gradient tool with white color on the stop points and different opacity values:

[image: gradient]

When I change the stop colors to solid colors, then the gradient renders similarly in Illustrator and in the PDF. I would rather avoid changing all my gradients to these colors.

Is it possible to make the opacity gradients work in CMYK with FOGRA 29?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in other documents? I mean both when making a drawing from scratch and when copying the emojis to another document. Any change if you change some color and export settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the white objects... look at the **Attributes Panel** in Illustrator (`Window > Attributes`) are they set to **overprint**?

Apparently Adobe, by default, may configure objects that contain white in a gradient to *overprint*. Don't ask me to explain the Adobe logic.... I really can't. They report something along the lines of... it's done intentionally so that "appearance remains consistent for gradients." Or something to that effect - I can't remember the *exact* explanation.

However, if you overprint white.. you end up getting.. well.. nothing. White doesn't print.

Ensure your white objects/gradients are **not** set to overprint in the **Attributes Panel**.

---

Note if you were to use 1% of *any* color, this issue is generally not present. It's only a problem when using 0% of all color (white), and more commonly with white in gradients or meshes.

Comment: I'm upvoting this because I suspect the issue does indeed have to do with the overprint setting. I can't however reproduce the problem. I've tried in both RGB and CMYK mode to turn on *Overprint Fill* on a white to transparent gradient on top of a red object and I can't make the white gradient disappear in a saved PDF! (In Acrobat I've previewed both with and without *Simulate Overprinting*). Does it indeed disappear if you save such a PDF?

Comment: There's some voodoo that takes place @Wolff -- It's not a *guarantee* that white object will *always* be set to overprint or will *always* merely vanish. It has a great deal to do with profiles, conversions, etc. I don't know the *exact* configuration of artwork that causes this to trigger (Adobe won't share it). But it's a common enough issue that checking overprint is generally the *first place* to look.

Comment: For the record, I've only seen it a few times over the years and it's **always** been in files I've received from someone else (or purchased stock vectors). I've never seen it triggered in my *own work*. So I don't know what steps users may be taking to actually cause it.

Comment: I agree that that one should always avoid overprinting white objects but also that problems are rare (I see a lot of client PDFs). There must be some logic to it. But we don't know all settings in the user's document.

Comment: Adobe simply won't share the "why" this happens.. `:)` .. or at least they wouldn't when the issue was brought up years ago. Best I can figure is `New Art Has Basic Appearance` is NOT ticked and the white object is drawn... remnants of overprinting are carried over.

Comment: @Wolff I updated the question with a screenshot of the Attributes panel: the white objects are not set to overprint. Change from white to another color does not affect the result in the PDF.

Comment: We generally don't do this... but I'm curious... Is there any possibility of sharing one of the images @miguelmorin ? I, honestly can't think of another reason this may happen. I'd need to examine the artwork. There **has** to be a reason for the white dropping out. -- And.. honestly.. one can't rule out that it's CS5. It may be a bug with transparency in that version of AI. Gradient transparency was still relatively new then.

Comment: Oh Wait!!!!! Are you using Preview to view the PDFs @miguelmorin ? Do they look different if you use Acrobat or Reader to view the PDFs? Preview is dumb when it comes to CMYK or printing technologies. It's for mom and pop to view photos not print workflows.

Comment: @Scott Yes, I was using Preview. I now installed Adobe Reader and Adobe Acrobat and the transparency renders fine in them. The manufacturer preview on the website was on Safari, which probably uses Preview as well and explains the lack of gradients. I'm happy to share the file if you want to inspect it.

Comment: Safari is an Apple product so it probably has some similar rendering code as Preview. I'm a Mac lover.. but.. the closed environment, and the fact that environment is no longer targeted to professionals, means you may do better by branching out.. Google Chrome, Firefox.. and see if those render better for the manufacturer's website. If the issue was the use of Preview, then file examination won't really make any difference.